# MySql: Is it possible to specify a unique compound key which applies a function to the columns?

Tags: mysql, ddl, unique-constraint

I have a MySQL table with the following structure:

```
Field       Type            Null  Key
updateTime  datetime        NO      
fixId       varchar(45)     NO      
seqno       int(11)         NO      
message     blob            YES     
direction   enum('S','R')   NO      
id          int(11)         NO   PRI
```

I would like to make a unique key which applies a function to one of the columns:

```
alter table messages add unique key (date(updateTime),fixId,direction,seqno);
```

i.e. apply the date() function to a datetime column so that there can only be one message per day which has that same combination of values.

I am getting a syntax error when I run the above DDL.  Is there a way to do use a function in a unique key definition?

Comment: No, keys are just the values of the fields, not functions.

Comment: Split the `updateTime` column into separate `updateDate` and `updateTimeOfDay` columns.